# Dropbox not uploading the changed files frequently

Tags: synchronization, dropbox

I have installed the dropbox and linked with eclipsed workspace but I have found that file which is on server is old one. I have made many changes using control s and its not saving

or is there any way by which I can manually click on sync now.

or any other software

Comment: This should probably be on http://webapps.stackexchange.com - there is currently no migration path to this site.

Comment: Maybe this is just me being weird, but it scares the hell out of me just to think that some people use DropBox for their source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed with dropbox that sometimes a file will not update, this happens a lot with my password safe file if I have it open on more then one machine. Could this be your problem?

It may not open if something is locking the file.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me frequently on Windows 7. Most of the times it is solved by exiting Dropbox (click on the Dropbox icon and select "exit") and then restarting drop-box again (find Dropbox in your start menu and select it).

Sometimes it will not sync even with a system restart, and I assume that there is some lag in the Dropbox infrastructure causing that.